# search word in google and want to find hits of each word using java program

Tags: java

I have 30000 dictionary words. In that I want to to search each word in Google and want to find hits of each word using Java program. Is it possible?

Comment: Why?  It doesn't sound like a useful thing to do, to me.  If you are looking for dictionary definitions, try an online dictionary website.  And check the Terms of Service first!!!!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question? You want to know how many results Google finds for each word of your list ?

Comment: bear in mind this is not legal

Comment: @Bozho: Really?  Under what jurisdiction?

Comment: under the terms of use of google. you might get your address blacklisted

Comment: @Bozho: Can you link those terms of use ?

Comment: http://www.google.com/intl/en/mobile/xhtml/terms_of_service.html: You may not send automated queries of any sort to Google's system without express permission in advance from Google.

Answer (score 1):

Look up `<estimatedTotalResultsCount>` using Google's [SOAP search API](http://code.google.com/apis/soapsearch/reference.html#search_results_format).
You'll be limited to 1000 queries per day though. This limit is removed if you use their [AJAX API](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/).

Comment: Hi JRL,
     I dont know AJAX. Will u able to give any ideas to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Since your [duplicate post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2156967/is-it-possble-to-retreive-page-source-from-google-search-automatically-by-using-j) is closed, I'll post my answer here as well:

> Whether this is possible or not doesn't really matter: Google doesn't want you to do that. They have a public AJAX-search API developers can use: http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/web.html

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend separating your problem into pieces.  Get each one working, then marry them together for the solution you want.

You have a few things going on here:

1. Downloading text from a URL
2. Scanning a stream of characters and breaking it up into words
3. Iterating through a list of words and tallying up the hits from your dictionary

Computer science is all about taking large problems and decomposing them into smaller ones.  I'd recommend that you start learning how to do that now.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Sun tutorial on [Reading to and Writing from an URLConnection](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html).

The simplest URL I can see to make a Google search is like:

> http://www.google.com/#q=wombat

Comment: No, just try it. You will get a 403 response code from Google, and perhaps even a ban if you continue to try it :). You could get around the 403 by faking your application is a browser by putting the necessary information in the header of your request, but as already noted by Bozho: it's against Google's term of use.

Comment: Right, I guess they block the Java user agent string.  You'd have to use curl or something like that.

Comment: Not just Java: anything that doesn't "look" like a browser.

Answer (score 0):

Reading from a url with java is pretty straight forward.  A basic working example is as follows

```
public Set<String> readUrl(String url) {

        String line;
        Set<String> lines = new HashSet<String>();

        try {
            URL url = new URL(url);
            URLConnection page = url.openConnection();

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(page.getInputStream()));

            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                lines.add(line);
            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return lines;
    }
```

Comment: No. See my comment to `danben`'s answer.