# java program to retreive page source from google search automatically

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [search word in google and want to find hits of each word using java program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2085454/search-word-in-google-and-want-to-find-hits-of-each-word-using-java-program)

hi friends,
 I want to write java program to retrieve page source from google search automatically. Its very urgent.Give any suggestions.