# is it possble to retreive page source from Google search automatically by using java program?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Java program to retreive page source from Google search automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2156111/java-program-to-retreive-page-source-from-google-search-automatically)

I just give any word in Google search and search the output for that particular word. I want Java program to retrieve page source from google search automatically for that particular word.

Comment: Please don't repeatedly post the same question.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2156111/java-program-to-retreive-page-source-from-google-search-automatically/2156135#2156135

Answer (score 2):

Whether this is possible or not doesn't really matter: Google doesn't want you to do that. They have a public AJAX-search API developers can use: http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/web.html

Answer (score 0):

The "page source" is the the raw HTML that is returned from the web server, so you can get this text by simply submitting an HTTP request to google, and reading the HttpResponse.

Check out the [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/) for Java for submitting an HTTP request.

Try running a Google search for any word.  Once you get to the search results page, look at what appears in the Address bar.  You'll probably want to submit something like this as an HTTP GET.

Comment: Note that you'll have to "fake" that your Java app is a browser, otherwise the Google server does not return anything (except an error message).